# Mimic smartphone tables with responsive design

Tags: css

I have a table with n columns and I'm using bootstrap for the design.

What I would like to do is to put the `td` with the left-class to stack up on the left and the right-class to stack up on the right (with centered element such as button or checkboxes and taking the minimum width). In the middle, I would like the other `td` to be in the middle, one below the other without padding or margin.

Here is an illustration of what I need:

[image]

I successfully rendered the middle part by doing so:

```
tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #eceeef;
}
td {
    padding:0px !important;
    padding-left:20px !important;
    border-top: none !important;
    width:100% !important;
    display: block;
}
```

I have troubles getting my left-class and my right-class to work... I've tried to use `float:left` but the problem is that it doesn't take the whole height and it doesn't work when it's not the first `td`. I've also tried the `inline-block` just for the side classes but it's taking most of the width and I couldn't stack them up (like the green zone).

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJwW2j0066Qx4WcVZY4n?p=preview) (need to play with the width to see the responsive design)

Here is my PUG code:

```
.table-responsive
    table.table.table-striped
        tbody
            tr
                td.left-class
                    input(type='checkbox')
                td test
                td test
                td test
                td test
                td test
                td.right-class
                    button click1
                td.right-class
                    button click2
```

Comment: You should also give your html code

Comment: Please provide us with a MCV example of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Please see my edit

Comment: @JuanFerreras I've added a plunker...please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tb0ykyn/2/)

I was able to make this only with jquery because for some reasons when i add this style from css it doesn't work but this i think will fix your problem

```
$('.right-class').css('display','block');
```

Comment: Please see the plunker

Comment: Thanks but I still see one problem... you're defining a fixed height!

Comment: And of course, ideally a 100% css would be a better solution...I really think there is a way without jquery

Comment: It's better but I don't think it's a satisfying solution either... First you have to know in advance how many blocks you'll have on the right side (btw why is it 60% and not 50%?) and in addition, if the number of td in the middle increases, everything is messed up!

Comment: This is the best way to do it. If you want it to be dynamically you should change the structure then

Comment: How can I change the structure to get a better result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121467/discussion-between-edisoni-1337-and-ncohen).